# BigQuery joining tables on repeated fields

Tags: google-bigquery

I have one table that contains id as single column and multiple columns that are nested.

1)

An example schema for better understanding :

id - String,

childrenNames - String repeated,

animalNames - String repeated,

Another table contains only single columns

2)

An example schema for better understanding :

childrenName - String,

animalName - String

I need to know all the records from table 2) that are not in table 1)
So both childrenName and animalName need to belong to one user, together.

I can add that I tried to select separately for each column from table 2) values that are **'IN'** lists from table 1) but if it returns any row it can also mean both are belonging to two different ids (or more).

Example row table 1)

id: 1234,

childrenNames : ['Ana', 'Frank'],

animalNames : ['Rex', 'Max'],

Example rows table 2)

A)

childrenName : 'Ana',

animalName : 'Ozzy'

B)

childrenName : 'Frank',

animalName : 'Rex'

For above examples I should get the row A) from table 2) because 'Ozzy' does not belong to the id 1234 (lets suppose we do not have more records in table 1)  )

Anyone idea how to solve such problem with BigQuery SQL (Standard or Legacy) ?

Comment: you should provide example of your data!

Comment: Thanks! I have just added it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT childrenName, animalName, ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT id) users
FROM `project.dataset.table2`
CROSS JOIN `project.dataset.table1`
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM UNNEST(childrenNames) cn WHERE cn = childrenName) > 0
AND (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM UNNEST(animalNames) an WHERE an = animalName) > 0
GROUP BY childrenName, animalName
```

You can test, play with above using data example for your question

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table1` AS (
  SELECT '1' id, ['Ana', 'Frank'] childrenNames,  ['Rex', 'Max'] animalNames 
), `project.dataset.table2` AS (
  SELECT 'Ana' childrenName, 'Ozzy' animalName UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Frank', 'Rex'
)
SELECT childrenName, animalName, ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT id) users
FROM `project.dataset.table2`
CROSS JOIN `project.dataset.table1`
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM UNNEST(childrenNames) cn WHERE cn = childrenName) > 0
AND (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM UNNEST(animalNames) an WHERE an = animalName) > 0
GROUP BY childrenName, animalName
```

with result

```
Row childrenName    animalName  users    
1   Frank           Rex         1
```

Note: field `users` in the output is a repeated string / array that consists list of users who have the search pair

The less verbose variation of above will be

```
#standardSQL
SELECT childrenName, animalName, ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT id) users
FROM `project.dataset.table2`
CROSS JOIN `project.dataset.table1`
WHERE childrenName IN UNNEST(childrenNames)
AND animalName IN UNNEST(animalNames)
GROUP BY childrenName, animalName
```

with exact same result

So, obviously - use this second one :o)

> ... Table 1) has 5mln records, Table 2) 200k - thus `Query exceeded resource limits`

Try below version

```
#standardSQL
WITH flatten_table1 AS (
  SELECT id, childrenName, animalName
  FROM `project.dataset.table1`, 
  UNNEST(childrenNames) childrenName,
  UNNEST(animalNames) animalName
)
SELECT childrenName, animalName, id
FROM `project.dataset.table2`
JOIN flatten_table1
USING(childrenName, animalName)
```

Comment: Would there be any optimization possible for the second query? I got  'Error: Query exceeded resource limits. 112320.34437458635 CPU seconds were used, and this query must use less than 46000.0 CPU seconds'   when running that one applied to my data.

Comment: start with removing `ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT id)` as it was extra or maybe better to start with first removing DISTINCT in that ARRAY_AGG

Comment: This error I got after removing that piece as well.

Comment: what error and what piece? also give us an idea of what your real data is - volume wise  - as in question you mentioned  - `(lets suppose we do not have more records in table 1`

Comment: Above mentioned error so ''Error: Query exceeded resource limits. 112320.34437458635 CPU seconds were used, and this query must use less than 46000.0 CPU seconds'. With piece I meant 'ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT id)' from the last query. Table 1) has 5mln records, Table 2) 200k

Comment: ok. so obviously cross join for such tables will end up with resources exceed issue. will take a look again later in a day when have time :o)

Comment: Changing JOIN for LEFT JOIN and adding 'where id is null' made query returning mismatches (id only exist in table 1).


#standardSQL
WITH flatten_table1 AS (
  SELECT id, childrenName, animalName
  FROM `project.dataset.table1`, 
  UNNEST(childrenNames) childrenName,
  UNNEST(animalNames) animalName
)
SELECT childrenName, animalName, id
FROM `project.dataset.table2`
LEFT JOIN flatten_table1
USING(childrenName, animalName)
where id is null   

Great! Thank you!